# json_decode() returns null on json object from AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, json

This is my `JSON` object:

```
[{\"tablevalue\":\"5\",\"$$hashKey\":\"object:82\"},{\"tablevalue\":\"11\",\"$$hashKey\":\"object:87\"}]
```

The `JSON` object is an array from AngularJS converted into `JSON` using `JSON.stringify`.

When I decode it using `json_decode()` in PHP it returns `null`.

Comment: that is the value that i got from an array json.stringify..

Comment: it already done.. i just stripped slashes it and it is now a valid json

Comment: Hi Kim Sean - if you've solved the problem yourself, then the best thing to do is to post your solution here as an Answer, then Accept it. That will remove the question from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem by using stripped slashes into it.